# How to create a simple image uploader for custom component

Tags: joomla-3.x, development, joomla-api, file-upload

I'm developing a custom component for creating, editing and saving data of single records including images. I know that in **admin/models/forms/record.xml** there must be field `name="image" type="file" accept="image/*"` but how and where do I need to write the simple php-code for uploading images to specific folder, in which file and how? Where to write the code from example by the link https://docs.joomla.org/How_to_use_the_filesystem_package ?

**EDITED:** Now I added in my **admin/com_mycom/controllers/record.php** the code:

```
public function save($data = array(), $key = 'id')
    {
        $file = JRequest::getVar('image', null, 'files', 'array');
        $filename = JFile::makeSafe($file['name']);
        $src = $file['tmp_name'];
        $dest = "media/com_mycom/img/".$filename;
        if (JFile::upload($src, $dest)) {
              //Redirect to a page of your choice
        } else {
              //Redirect and throw an error message
        }
        parent::save();
    }
```

$data = array(), $key = 'id' I got from function allowEdit()

**SOLVED BUT...** So the problem was in the name of input. JRequest::getVar contains 'image' but input type="file" has name="**jform[image]**". I've found the code:

```
$jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
$files = $jinput->files->get('jform');
$file = $files['image'];
```

instead of

```
$file = JRequest::getVar('image', null, 'files', 'array');
```

and now the file is being uploaded but unfortunately its name is not being updated in the DB

Ok, I've added under `if (JFile::upload($src, $dest)) {` the code:

```
$thisID = JRequest::getVar('id');
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$fields = array($db->quoteName('image') . " = " . $db->quote($filename));
$conditions = array($db->quoteName('id') . " = " . $thisID);
$query->update($db->quoteName('#__mycom'))->set($fields)->where($conditions);
$db->setQuery($query);
$db->execute($query);
```

but is there some simplest way to update filename in the DB ?

Comment: Hi - were you able to solve - ca you help me on similar - http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/17311/how-to-save-image-in-specified-folder-in-joomla-directory-and-save-file-name-in

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should add it to your controller, probably `controllers/record.php`. Override `save` function.

```
public function save($key = NULL, $urlVar = NULL)
{
  // Upload your image

  // Save item
  parent::save();
}
```

**UPDATE**

**"Failed to move file" error**

This came from wrong `$dest` value. Destination has to be full path.

**Wrong:**

```
$dest = "media/com_mycom/img/".$filename;
```

**Correct:**

```
$dest = JPATH_SITE."/media/com_mycom/img/".$filename;
```

Comment: Thanks. Now I get the Warning: Failed to move file! All the needed folders have 0777

Comment: Please update your question and add `save` function to it. Is `/tmp` folder also include in "all the needed foldser"? Usually this error gomes if `/tmp` folder is not writable. Go to `System > System Information > Directory Permissions` and recheck if all directories are writable.

Comment: Yes, tmp also has 0777 and all the directories on the Directory Permissions tab are writable

Comment: Does your form have attribute `enctype="multipart/form-data"`? If not, then files won't be uploaded.

Comment: Yes, it does and name of image file is being saved successfully in the DB but file doesn't move to the folder

Comment: Does folder `media/com_mycom/img/` exist? It sounds like permission issue. Maybe your folder has no user for apache? If your server runs on Linux, it should be `www-data` if I'm not mistaken. Could you check users for that folder? You could try to upload file directly to `media` folder (just for temporary testing), since this was created with Joomla! install, it should have all correct permissions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22828/discussion-between-rene-korss-and-stckvrw).

Comment: Hi - were you able to solve - ca you help me on similar - http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/17311/how-to-save-image-in-specified-folder-in-joomla-directory-and-save-file-name-in

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to refer administrator part of `com_media` component. It has all file upload related functionality developed.

It also includes error handling and other checks related to file system.